# iphone NSDate Problem

Tags: iphone, nsdate

Following code I can use for storing the value of UILabel into a string. And Value of string is store into NSDate.

```
NSString *star = [[NSString alloc]init];
star = lbtInDate.text;
NSString *end = [[NSString alloc]init];
end = lblOutDate.text;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
NSDate *sdate= [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:star];
NSDate *edate=[dateFormatter1 dateFromString:end];
```

but the value of sdate and edate is shows nil. so please help how can i store the value of UILabel into NSDate for compare.

Comment: Two things: are you sure that `lbtInDate` and `lblOutDate` are connected in your xib file (not nil)? And, how are you checking the value of `sdate` and `edate`?

Comment: Also, just a quick note: you don't have to do `NSString *foo = [[NSString alloc] init]; foo = ...;`. This actually leaks memory Instead you should just do `NSString *foo = ...;`.

Comment: Just NSLog star and end before converting it to date, so that you can make sure you are geting values from label(not lable)..

Comment: I think you are not getting result because your date formatter is not correct for reference go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087173/nsdateformatter-and-yyyy-mm-dd/5087344#5087344 ..... also cross check that you are getting values in star and end variables .... also you dont need to use [[NSString alloc]init] with these tw variables (it is a leak here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfectly valid only the `lbtInDate.text;` and `lblOutDate.text;` respect the date format. If not your NSDate's will be null.

If `lblOutDate.text;` is something like `@"2002-12-23"`, your date format should be `@"yyyy-MM-dd"` and so on.

[Data Formatting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1)