# How to get value from datetime picker and set that value on tableviewcell in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have here a problem on datetime picker. I want to know how to set datetime picker value on tableview cell.

I have created two controller classes. One controller's name is display class and the other controller's name is datetime. I have this second controller page with name display and datetime.

If I start the application I am passing from display page to datetime page and here I have selected a value from datetime page on datetimepickerview and which value I am select this value should auto set on 1controller class on tableview cell.

Would someone give me a hint on how to do this?

Comment: Do you have custome cell ? or UITableviewCell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your datetimepickervalue in appDelegate file variable. So you can define one sting in your appDelegate file like below

In appDelegate.h file

```
NSString *strDate;
```

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strDate;

In appDelegate.m file

```
@synthesize strDate;
```

Now, In Your dateselection controller write below line in viewDidLoad Method.

```
YourAppNameDelegate *appDelegate=  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Now, when you done with date selection and before you go back to First view do below.

```
 appDelegate.strDate = [self convertDueDateFormat];


-(NSString *)convertDueDateFormat{
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
  [dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior: NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
  NSString *strDateFormat = NSLocalizedString(@"dateFormat", nil);
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:strDateFormat];
  NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:pkrDueDate.date];
  return dateString;
}
```

Now, in your firstviewcontroller.h file take below label.

```
UILable *lblDate;
```

And in your cellForRowIndexPath Datasource method of your tableview. write below.

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"    ";
lblDate = cell.detailTextLabel;
```

And in viewWillAppear Method write below.

```
lblDate.text = appDelegate.strDate;
```

Comment: Are you displaying date in textLabel or detailTextLabel ?

Comment: displaying date in detailtextlabel

Comment: I have modified my answer.Check please.

Comment: i have done the code but in the label null value is returning

Comment: and when i run the application picker does not show the current time

Comment: First time it would be blank. But when you come back to first view again after selection date then it would have value in cell. Did you make sure you pass value from dateview in correct function. Are you using navigation based app ?

Comment: my application is windows based and the cell does not show value when i select the time from picker and get back to first view

Comment: The code is working for me. You should check your application flow. Whether when you set date is calling before first view controller viewWillAppear or not by putting breakpoint.

Comment: @Rani let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1723/discussion-between-deeps-and-rani)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want to set date in some UI like label or textField, means you need date in NSString, so to get NSString form NSDate go to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087173/nsdateformatter-and-yyyy-mm-dd/5087344#5087344)

Now to get NSDate form UIDatePicker simply access its property `date`

Now to resolve your passing value to VC1 do like this

1. pass a reference of NSDate to your second VC2 (which select date from picker), that is make a variable of type in NSDate in VC1 and VC2 (let it be dateVc1 and dateVc2)
2. when you show VC2 set dateVc2=dateVC1
3. when you come back to VC1 use dateVc1 and change it to NSString, for how to change the above link will help you in that