# how to set the in setdateformat in datepicker coding not use in xib..... Im using DatePicker in Format @"yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"

Tags: iphone

The output comes, for example: 17-10-1990 18:30:00 +0000. When we retrieve the value in NSDateFormatter the day is changed to 16-10-1990. No error comes.

```
NSDateFormatter *sdayFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[sdayFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *sdayString = [sdayFormat stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
```

please help me. I'm new in iphone developer.

Answer (score 0):

to see how to set dateFormatter go to [this link - NSDateFormatter and yyyy-MM-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087173/nsdateformatter-and-yyyy-mm-dd/5087344#5087344)

and to see the list of all possible formats go to [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out!

```
    NSString *tDate = @"17-10-1990 18:30:00 +0000";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z:"];

NSDate *fDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:tDate];

NSLog(@"Given date :%@ - Converted Date :%@",tDate,fDate);
```

use this link as reference for any date related operations

http://www.stepcase.com/blog/2008/12/02/format-string-for-the-iphone-nsdateformatter/

Hope this helps