# Convert Formate of internet time to Nsdate Format in Desire

Tags: iphone

2011-08-06T12:29:10.703+05:30 
i have following  date that i have convert in this format like

"2011-08-06T12:29:10+05:30"

Answer (score 0):

[**Here**](http://www.stepcase.com/blog/2008/12/02/format-string-for-the-iphone-nsdateformatter/) is a nice blog to have a better idea...

Answer (score 0):

A more better explain is [on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087173/nsdateformatter-and-yyyy-mm-dd/5087344#5087344)

You can see that you need more than one date `NSDateFormater` for this job