# Convert NSDate to other format

Tags: objective-c, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSDateFormatter and yyyy-MM-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087173/nsdateformatter-and-yyyy-mm-dd)

I have an NSDate variable in format yyyy-MM-dd that I want to convert to dd/MM/yyyy. How can I do it?

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];            
NSDate *date = [f dateFromString:[[jugador objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"FECHA_NAC"]];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using same NSDateformatter u can format date using **setDateFormat** and retreive date using **dateFromString**

For example :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSString *strToday = [dateFormat1  stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];// string with yyyy-MM-dd format

[dateFormat1 setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

NSDate *todaydate = [dateFormat1 dateFromString:strToday];// date with dd/MM/yyyy format
```

**EDIT** : changes in code of `example`

Comment: This answer is wrong. dateFromString gets string and not date .

Comment: the last line of code is still wrong.

Comment: @vikingosegundo : code was example you can also edit it no need to panic

Comment: @Curnelious code was example you can also edit it no need to panic

Comment: it is usually beneficial if sample code is correct. and if fellow programmers spot an error you shouldn't be snippy.

Comment: is there a way to do this without using nsstring? just seems like an unnecessary extra step

Answer (score 2):

After you call `dateFromString:`, just set the desired format on the same date formatter and call `stringFromDate:`.