# TimeStamp in iOS objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, timestamp

I need a timestamp in iOS objective c in the format of dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss. Could anyone help me to achieve this? I am using the following code. but no luck

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
        [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2012-02-07 14:09:46"];
        NSTimeInterval interval = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
        
        NSLog(@"date = %f", interval);
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? What's not working? What's the debug? Is `date` nil?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901764/convert-nsdate-to-other-format

Comment: How You can get dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss when You use date format of yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:s

Answer (score 0):

`NSDate` and `NSDateFormatter` are two different things.
One keeps the date, the other keeps the format.
So you can change the format again and ask the formatter to return the/a date as string in the new given format. This is handy because you can compare NSDate with NSDate and keep the format aside for comparison.

It's so easy, you will cry. 
You just need to change the format as you like and re-apply your date to the receiver (NSDateFormatter)

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2012-02-07 14:09:46"];
NSTimeInterval interval = [date timeIntervalSince1970];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *secondDateFormatString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"date = %f %@", interval, secondDateFormatString);
```