# Dateformatting when UILabel is getting date from datepicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

I have datepicker, a button and a label. The label says "Choose your date", the datepicker is, yeah, a datepicker and the button transfers the date the user picked into the label, like this: "You chose the date 2013-01-18 02:28:58 +0000".

How can I get the date format to be: "You chose the date 18/01-2013" ??? Without the time and the day/month/year set up?

The code I have in the button IBAction for the transfer to label is:

```
NSString *words = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"You chose the date %@", dateSelected];
settDato.text = words;
```

Comment: use [`NSDateFormater`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5087173/593709)

Comment: Yeah, I figured that much out by Google, but the problem is that i don't know where to put it in my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSDateFormatter`, in your `.h` have

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` or `init` method is best

```
formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM-YYYY"];
```

Then in your `IBAction`

```
NSString *words = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You chose the date %@", [formatter stringFromDate:dateSelected]];
settDato.text = words;
```